# web.config in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, azure

I want to know what configuration is needed in web.config if I deploy my ASP.NET application to Windows Azure.

Note: - I used Entity Model (System.Data.EntityClient)
         and I had used two data sources

Comment: Are you having specific issues with your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Azure to host your EF data? In that case, build your app to use your live  SQL Azure connection strings and it should be fine when you deploy.

If you're not using SQL Azure ... you have all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP.NET web application in Windows Azure can read settings from the web.config the same way it would if it is on-premise.  However, you will not be able to modify your web.config without redeploying your Azure package.

If you wish to have the ability to change configuration settings on the fly, then you should move those settings into the ServiceConfiguration file for your cloud project for Auzre.  If you do not need the ability to change a setting on the fly, then you can simply leave it in your web.config.